# Recommended Request Correlation Approach across Loggers in ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net-core

`ILogger` has a `BeginScope` method which is intended for correlation I guess. I put together a sample: https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AspNetVNextSamples/blob/3d36cdb4c2072d333d0e2583894c5616875ad8ed/src/LoggingSample/Startup.cs

The correlation seems to be working with NLog implementation in my sample. However, with my approach above, I wasn't able to find a way to enable scoping between logger types. I solved this using only one logger inside my application.

What is the recommended way for request correlation across loggers in ASP.NET vNext?

Comment: when you say logger types , you mean Nlog and log4Net . or in a different way